# Realtime database fires child_removed and child_added after pushing

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying out the node.js Admin SDK to push items and listen to updates on a Realtime Database:

```
ref.child('something').on('child_added', childAdded)
ref.child('something').on('child_changed', childChanged)
ref.child('something').on('child_removed', childRemoved)

...

ref.child('something').push({...})
```

If I push 3 items, I expect to get `childAdded` to be called 3 times with each item. Sometimes this is what happens, other times this (after the 3rd add):

`childRemoved` called twice for the 2 existing items

`childAdded` called 3 times for the 2 existing items and the new item

Is this normal? How can I avoid `child_removed` callbacks for existing items?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the strange was behavior was caused by a transaction on the parent object as part of adding/removing children.

The transaction was sometimes being called with no data, in which case I was returning an empty/placeholder object and that was apparently causing `child_removed` events to be fired. The transaction would run again with actual data and the children would seemingly added back.

**Solution:** Set the `applyLocally` parameter of the transaction to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a `limit` on your query, in which case this is the expected behavior.

A Firebase Realtime Database query gives you a view on the subset of the data. Say that you have a node with chat messages, and you create a query to get the last 3 chat messages:

```
ref.child('messages').orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(3)
```

Initially this will give you the 3 most recent chat messages, say with timestamps:

- 1677076200112
- 1677076200175
- 1677076200196

Now let's say somebody adds a new chat message with timestamp:

- 1677076222060

The database will now fire a `child_added` event for the new child node, and a `child_removed` event for the oldest one of the snapshot it gave you before to ensure that your still have the latest **3** messages as you requested in the query.

Comment: I don't have a limit on my query (that I'm aware of). Does the Admin SDK apply a built-in limit? Also the case you describe makes sense, but in my case 2 items are removed first, then they're added again along with the new item.